# CSS hover effect doesn't appear on adding background image

Tags: html, css

I have added a css hover effect on the button which is inside the div `main-container`. Also inside it is a `background` div with a `layer` div inside of it. The problem is everytime, there is a background image the hover effect doesn't show but if I remove the background image, the effect is visible. How do I fix this? [***demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/cG5EH/52/)

```css
.background {
    position: relative;
}

.background  img{
    max-width:100%;
 max-height:800px;
}

.layer {
    background-color: rgba(248, 247, 216, 0.7);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.btn {
 border: none;
 font-family: inherit;
 font-size: inherit;
 color: inherit;
 background: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 25px 80px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 15px 30px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 font-weight: 700;
 outline: none;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}

.btn:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}

.btn:before {
 speak: none;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 text-transform: none;
 line-height: 1;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

/* Button 1 */
.btn-1 {
 border: 3px solid #fff;
 color: #fff;
}

.btn-1f {
 overflow: hidden;
}

.btn-1f:after {
 width: 101%;
 height: 0;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 background: #000;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.btn-1f:hover,
.btn-1f:active {
 color: #0e83cd;
}

.btn-1f:hover:after {
 height: 75%;
 opacity: 1;
}

.btn-1f:active:after {
 height: 130%;
 opacity: 1;
}
.background {
    position: relative;
 width: inherit;
 height:inherit;
 background-image: url("http://www.wallpapereast.com/static/images/nature-wallpaper-desktop-308_ySxPe7m.jpg");
}
.main-container{
 width:100%;
 height:745px;
 position:relative;
}
.cities{position:absolute;bottom:0;}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
<div class="background">
  <div class="layer">
</div>
</div>
<div class="cities"><p>
<button class="btn btn-1 btn-1f"><a href="#">Bangalore</a></button>   
</p> 
</div>
```

Comment: jsFiddle isn't opening for me. Can you create a local snippet by [edit]ing the question and pressing Ctrl + M?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. 
I know the background-image is always on top of the background-color. You can try to fix it using z-index.

Comment: Please consider upvoting answers in case they are helpful, to be thankful of time and effort people invest on your problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I checked your code.
GIVE Z-index negative on background like below,**

```
.background {
    background-image: url("http://www.wallpapereast.com/static/images/nature-wallpaper-desktop-308_ySxPe7m.jpg");
    height: inherit;
    position: relative;
    width: inherit;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may do this:

```
.btn{
    z-index: 99;
}
.btn:hover a{
    color: #efefef;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Give the button a `z-index`.

Eg : `z-index: 999;`